# Using Android only with Outlook and not Google Calendar

Tags: sync, calendar, outlook

When using Android ICS, can I use my phone without having my calendar and associated items going on Google Calendar but just synchronizing with Outlook (the desktop app) ? If yes, how may I do this ?

Comment: Related: [Sync contacts and calendar from Outlook 2010 on my laptop with Android phone, avoid data in cloud?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46816)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sync Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955). With the right settings I think it can accomplish what you want. If it's not what you're looking for you can try [Outlook Mobile Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.karya.outlookcalendar.screens) but it only has 3.5 (EDIT: 2) stars.

Comment: 2 stars, at the moment.

Comment: [Karya Outlook Mobile Calendar](http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps/app/com.karya.outlookcalendar.screens/Outlook-Mobile-Calendar) has been pulled from Google Play Store. It has awful reviews on AndroidPIT and they say it's a lie that it's free, it's only 30-day free trial, anyway people say it doesn't sync, it crashes etc. etc. Avoid.